# Identity of message publisher

Tags: ros, node, publisher, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to find out who published a message (node name), especially for the topic tf, where many nodes are publishing different transforms.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216117/identity-of-message-publisher/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2015-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By using the [MessageEvent](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#MessageEvent_.5BROS_1.1.2B-.5D) callback signature you can use the `getPublisher()` function to retrieve the publisher name (in roscpp). The same appears to be possible in rospy by using [Connection Information](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Connection_Information).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-08-19**:
I see that this doesn't work when using Connection Information and bags as the callerid will always be the rosbag player, is it the same case for cpp?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2015-08-19**:
If you play back bags, rosbag effectively is the publisher. I think the connection header approach will therefore not work with rosbag. I'm not sure there is a way to recover the publisher id when playing back bagfiles (I guess not).